# Importing Android Project Into Eclipse Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import

I am trying to run an imported Android Project but I have run into a few errors. A big red exclamation mark is on both the project folder I want to run and the android-support-v7-appcompat folder.

Here are some screenshots that can hopefully help locate the issue.

1) Screen shots from the Android project I want to run:

Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Exports tab. There is a red X on Android Dependencies.

[image]

Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Exports tab. There is a red X on Android Dependencies.

[image]

Properties -> Android -> Library

[image]

Properties -> Andoid -> Android 4.4.2 is checked, API 19

Android Manifest minSDK and target SDK:

[image]

Here is the libs folder of the Android Project I want to run:

[image]

---

2) Screenshots from the android-support-v7-appcompat folder:

res -> values-v21 error

[image]

Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Exports tab.
[image]

Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries tab.
[image]

Properties -> Android -> Android 4.4.2 is checked, API 19

Libs folder:

[image]

Android Manifest minSDK:

[image]

I am very new to the Android process, and setting up this imported project correctly is quite confusing. Any help or detailed instructions on how to possibly fix the problem would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using Eclipse instead of the Google supported Android Studio?

Comment: Yes, I have to use Eclipse for this project, according to my class.

Comment: Go to your Project, right click, Android Tools --> Fix Project Properties

Comment: I clicked fix project properties on both the project I want to run and the android-support-v7-appcompat folder, as well as refreshed and cleaned, and nothing has changed.

Comment: I am getting an error saying: Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list and  Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies, I am not sure how to go about fixing this.

Answer (score 2):

@Bret:If you are facing issue with supportv4.jar version,then try to copy paste the your app's jar file into compact project or vice versa.Make sure you have same jar file in both project and library project.

It will remove your dependency issue of jar mismatch...

Answer (score 0):

Delete `android.library.reference.1=../appcompat_v7` from project.properties file.
Remove all dependency of appcompat_v7 from your project.
Clean->build->Run

Comment: From project which you want to run(imported project)

Comment: I removed the line you said to, but what do you mean by "remove all dependency of appcomp_v7 from your project" What steps to I have to do? Or is simply deleting that one line sufficient?

Comment: Clean and build project, you need to remove lines which have reference to appcompat library.